# Non-Designated Initializers (Compiler Flag Warning)

Tags: c++, c++20, compiler-warnings, designated-initializer

Let us assume we have the following code:

```cpp
struct MyStruct
{
    double height, width;
};

int main()
{
    const MyStruct a { 5.1, 2.3 };
    const MyStruct b { .height = 3.5, .width = 1.8 };

    return 0;
}
```

Since C++20 we have [Designated Initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers), which means we can use syntax like `{ .height = 3.5, .width = 1.8 }`. Now, if the internal order of fields `height` and `width` changes, then `{ 5.1, 2.3 }` still works (even though it's incorrect now). Whereas `{ .height = 3.5, .width = 1.8 }` fails to compile, which requires us to correct the initialization order.

So I was wondering, if there were any compiler flags (in g++ or msvc) to **warn** about the **usage** of **non-designated initializers** like `{ 5.1, 2.3 }`? This could help identify cases, where the internal order was switched without updating (or incorrectly updating) usages elsewhere in a library.

Comment: I don't thing there is a warning for that... but should probably done "easily" with clang tooling.